# filter multiple separate rows in a DataFrame that meet the condition in another DataFrame with pandas?

Tags: pandas

This is my DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'uid': [109200005, 108200056, 109200060, 108200085, 108200022],
    'grades': [69.233627, 70.130900, 83.357011, 88.206387, 74.342212]})
```

This is my condition list which comes from another DataFrame

```
condition_list = [109200005, 108200085]
```

I use this code to filter records that meet the condition

```
idx_list = []
for i in condition_list:
    idx_list.append(df[df['uid']==i].index.values[0])
```

and get what I need

```
>>> df.iloc[idx_list]
uid grades
0   109200005   69.233627
3   108200085   88.206387
```

Job is done. I'd just like to know is there a simpler way to do the job?

Comment: `df.loc[df['uid'].isin(condition_list)].drop_duplicates('uid')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang What is that supposed to be?

Comment: dont think you need the `drop_duplicates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df[df['uid'].isin(condition_list)]
```